# Making my own website with server

Tags: javascript, java, php, rest

I am making my own website and I've never really done it before. I am familiar with each of the separate parts, but I've never put them all together before.

I want to have html and javascript on the front end. This would send HTTP requests to my PHP on the backend. The PHP would then have an open socket with my java server that would store data in mysql or mongodb.

javascript client, PHP backend, Java server, mysql/mongo database.

Is this the appropriate way to set up a restful api in a general sense? If not, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it right. Javascript on the front end and PHP on the backend is an incredibly popular and powerful combination. The Apache server seems to be more popular among PHP users, but a java server works just fine.

Comment: A quick followup question, are you supposed to create sockets on PHP to talk to the server? The internet says that you should not create front-end javascript sockets, so I assumed that you are supposed to create them on your PHP backend to communicate with your own server sockets.

Comment: PHP is used for server side logic. In most cases, you wouldn't tend to open a web socket from a server to itself. Sockets tend to be more client to server side, or between two servers.